# What Colors should I use for changed/added Items?

Tags: color, color-theory, applications

I am programming an Application that manages a Database. The User can add Items to the List or modify them. These Items should be colored.

The Background ios white, and the currently selected Item is Blue (Standard Windows 7 Colors). Those are "immutable".
What Colors are nice for Changed and Added? At the moment I have Green and Yellow, which makes anyones Eyes bleed.

[image: Screenshot of the relevant part of my Application]

As I am a Programmer, making things look "nice" (aka Non-horrible) is not my forte...

Comment: I'd probably: lose the borders completely, keep blue background for selected, make new entries **bold** and edited entries *italic* or underlined. Basically I'd use font stylings instead of background colours, but that's mostly because I have no idea what the rest of your app looks like.

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. E. suggests, it's not quite the colours that are the problem here--it's the fact that you rendered them as borders. Rendering them as a background colour is way better, just like on the selection. It's rather impossible to recommend actual colours without knowing what the rest of your app design looks like, but there's a couple you should *not* use:

- **Blue**: already in use. Another shade might work, but it's risky.
- **Red**: suggests danger, error or removal.
- **Grey**: doesn't stand out, might be overlooked.

Personally, I'd also go for a bit more of a lighter shade / tint of these colours, in order to avoid the list looking like a Christmas tree. But that's subjective, I guess.

Comment: There's no way we can recommended a colour without knowing what the rest of the design looks like. +1 for backgrounds over borders though.